# Column selection in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

Is it possible to select only particular columns of a matrix? E.g. I have a 10x100 shaped matrix and I only would like to get these 4 columns: 231, 82, 12, 493.

Comment: A reference I suggest looking at: [Matrix indexing in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html).

Comment: Since the link above appears to be broken, here's an updated one: https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. If your matrix is named `A` then `A(:, [3,7,12,89])` will retrieve the columns numbered 3, 7, 12, and 89.